# Bootstrap 3 btn-group width changes using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

When I used a static way to display all buttons radio, it works fine(100% width), but the problem with the dynamic one using the **ng-repeat** I have a line break.

**Without ng-repeat:**
[image]

**With ng-repeat:**
[image]

**A code snippet:**

```
<div class="btn-group input-group btn-group-justified" ng-repeat="number in numbers">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'{{number}}'">{{number}}</label>
</div>
```

[**THE EXAMPLE**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UOQLh3Sq3nZPR6dv4oM6?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/LFiWKeAdL5FMDrRmpLoP?p=preview

move ng-repeat to `<label>`

```
   <div class="btn-group input-group btn-group-justified">
      <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="model.radioModel" btn-radio="{{number}}" ng-repeat="number in numbers" ng-init="model =$parent" name="radio">{{number}}</label>

    </div>
```

Comment: Why you can select many options in the same time(It's a radio button)?